gnuplot storing command output to a variable
How do you save the output from a gnuplot command into a (string) variable?   For example, I need to know the current xdata format setting in a "call"ed helper script, but I cannot recall the trick to save it. e.g.
gnuplot> show xdata

       x is set to time

But how do I save or gain access to this state?
I don't see any GP_VAL variable which makes this state available, and I am sure there are other states too, which are hard to access in a script.
Many thanks :-)

What exactly do you want to do if you have the format? Typically, you are setting the format in your script yourself, so you should know what it is. I can only imagine that you want to automate something or some external scripts are setting the format. Could you please explain in more detail what you want to do?

It is for when a small re-usable helper script needs to know what the caller has set.

In the past, I also wished that some parameters which you can display via show ... could be put into a variable. I'm not aware that this can be done with gnuplot easily now, but maybe in the future?
As I understand your question you want to find out within the script if xdata is set to time or not. If you check help xdata the setting can either be time or numeric.
One possible workaround to find out:

you can save your current script to a text file via save (check help save), apparently you can't save it to a datablock.
parse this text file to see whether, xdata is set to timedata. If it's set to time the line to find is set xdata time and if it's set to numeric the line is set xdata only which makes it a bit more difficult to extract (maybe there is an easier way).
The file will look like this:

#    
#       G N U P L O T
#       Version 6.0 patchlevel 0    last modified 2023-12-09 
#    
#       Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2023
#       Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others
#    
#       gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
#       faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
#       immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')
# set terminal qt 0 font "Sans,10"
# set output
unset clip points
set clip one
unset clip two
unset clip radial
set errorbars front 1.000000 
set border 31 front lt black linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid
set cornerpoles
set zdata 
set ydata 
set xdata time
set y2data 
set x2data 
set boxwidth
set boxdepth 0
set style fill  empty border
...

Unfortunately, gnuplot is not made for parsing, but you nevertheless can do it.
Script: (requires gnuplot>=6.0 because of function block)
### return setting for xdata
reset session

function $xdata(none) <<EOF
    FILE = "Settings.txt"
    save FILE 
    set table $Dummy
        plot FILE u 0:(strcol(2) eq "xdata" ? \
             XDATA=(strlen(' '.strcol(3))>3 ? "time" : "numeric") : 0) w table
    unset table
    return XDATA
EOF

set xdata
print $xdata(0)

set xdata time
print $xdata(0)
### end of script

Result:
numeric
time

Script: (requires gnuplot>=5.0.0 because of datablocks)
### return setting for xdata
reset session

set xdata
FILE = "SO78723633.txt"
save FILE 
set table $Dummy
    plot FILE u 0:(strcol(2) eq "xdata" ? \
         XDATA=(strlen(' '.strcol(3))>3 ? "time" : "numeric") : 0) w table
unset table
print XDATA

set xdata time
FILE = "SO78723633.txt"
save FILE 
set table $Dummy
    plot FILE u 0:(strcol(2) eq "xdata" ? \
         XDATA=(strlen(' '.strcol(3))>3 ? "time" : "numeric") : 0) w table
unset table
print XDATA
### end of script

Result:
numeric
time

Addition:
As mentioned in the comments, the above solutions are dependent on the setting for the datafile separator. If this has been set, e.g. to set datafile separator comma these solutions won't work.
Hence, here is a solution which is using a system dependent call, however, which works under Windows without first having to install some utilities like grep, gawk, coreutils, etc. The saved script file is read 1:1 into a datablock and then checked via strstrt() (check help strstrt).
Script: (requires gnuplot>=5.2.0, because of indexing datablocks)
set xdata time     # e.g. set in the caller script

TEMP = "Temp.txt"
save TEMP
FileToDatablock(f,d) = GPVAL_SYSNAME[1:7] eq "Windows" ? \
                       sprintf('< echo   %s ^<^<EOD  & type "%s"',d,f) : \
                       sprintf('< echo "\%s   <<EOD" & cat  "%s"',d,f) # Linux/MacOS
load FileToDatablock(TEMP,'$Settings')

do for [i=1:|$Settings|] {
    if (strstrt($Settings[i],'set xdata')==1) { XDATA = $Settings[i] }
}
print XDATA

Result:
set xdata time


Excellent, I thought there might have been a "trick" with something like gprintf, or the like, that I could not remember.  Thank you for including a Ver 5.0 solution.  Alternatively one could fgrep (or whatever) the file if that is tolerable.  The solution works in a small helper script that is "call"ed, which was my requirement - a re-usable script does not know what the caller has set.

@mjp ok, I see. If possible, I prefer gnuplot-only solutions which are platform-independent. However, a caveat for this solution is that your "caller" script might have done a set datafile separator comma, then the strcol(3) thing will not work. Then you could set it temporarily to whitespace and set it back to whatever it was before. However, for this to find out, you have to do show datafile. Argh...! So, then a system dependent grep or the like might be necessary in the end. Maybe there is still a gnuplot-only way.

Ah, yes, one of the other 'states' I mentioned that are missing.  I'm not sure what the best gnuplot fix is.  It is a few years since I last presented bug fixes, & I am not too keen to dive in again ATM.  Adding more GPVAL_ vars is limited as there may always be other situations or things might get missed.  Perhaps creating a gprintf() "%C", or letting the evaluate return the commands text like the system("cmd") command can, is the best.  Maybe we should look at how evaluate is coded & compare with system()

Simple answer if you don't mind creating a temp file via standard *nix shell commands.
gnuplot> set xdata time
gnuplot> tempfile = system("mktemp")
gnuplot> save tempfile
gnuplot> query = "grep 'set xdata' " . tempfile
gnuplot> response = system(query)
gnuplot> print response
set xdata time


Thank you, a good easy solution as I have an old Mac (and macports is currently broken with gnuplot at about 5.0).  The only niggle with this is that I see there is no way of checking if the system call fails.  GPVAL_ERRNO does not seem to be set when I test this.  Perhaps this is a bug that has been fixed.

Gnuplot does the simple thing and executes system shell commands via popen(). But popen() only returns an error if the pipe creation fails, not if there is a failure at the other end of a successfully opened pipe.
